# How to set a favicon to change daily

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 8 favicons that need to change daily in a specific order. The order will never change.

If I titled my favicons: favicon1.png, favicon2.png ... etc, what is the best way to have the correct favicon pulled each day? Is this javascript?

This page ([Can I change a favicon daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585932/can-i-change-a-favicon-daily)) is regarding the same question, but after reading through it, I am still unsure how to correctly set it up. Furthermore, I read that to bypass the heavy caching, I need to move the images outside of the root directory. How is this done? I am using Ubuntu's Apache.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change a favicon daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585932/can-i-change-a-favicon-daily)

Answer (score 1):

```
var today=new Date(),
    day=today.getDay()+1,//from 1 to 7 (1 is sunday then monday...)
    link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');

link.type = 'image/x-icon';
link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
link.href = 'urlPath/favicon'+day+'.png';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Will this still work since I have 8 favicons rather than 7?

Comment: well, the days in the week are 7, so favicons should be 7 or less... if you need a continue cicle of favicons and you need to change it daily, you need to save in server or localstorage the last favicon name